# element not visible when click to link in the cycle

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get all the links from the `odds-co` class. Then in the cycle, I `click` on each of them. But from time to time I get the error `element not visible`. I understand that this is due to timing. Specifying `time.sleep ()` seems to me not a very correct approach. I think 
can somehow use `webdriver wait`, but I don’t understand how.

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.odds-co')
for i in rows:
    i.click()
```

url - https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/efl-trophy/shrewsbury-macclesfield-WUgMbMnT/#over-under;2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expected_conditions.visibility_of()` receive WebElement as parameter

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.odds-co')
for row in rows:
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of(row)).click()
```

You can also wait for all the rows to be presence

```
rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table-container:not([style="display: none;"]) .odds-co')))
for row in rows:
    row.click()
```

Comment: `TimeoutException`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 but it works with `time.sleep()`? added another option.

Comment: No, it doesn't work with `time.sleep()`, too. I tried with `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 I added another option, but if `time.sleep()` doesn't work it's not timing issue (assuming the site isn't very very slow).

Comment: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Did you `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202142/discussion-between-m0nte-cr1st0-and-guy).

Answer (score 1):

The number of row present at table is 15 however when you search it in DOM it is showing 16.`Over/Under 4.25 is missing.`

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_all_elements_located`() and check 12 element and continue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/efl-trophy/shrewsbury-macclesfield-WUgMbMnT/#over-under;2")
rows=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".odds-co >a")))
for row in range(len(rows)):

    rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".odds-co >a")))
    if row==11:
        continue
    else:
        rows[row].click()
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is because that element is missing on webpage

Comment: How to programmatically identify such an element?

Comment: Yes we can do that other way.Give me some time I Will update